# passing a string variable in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, variables

I am creating a menu list with php. I want the user to change name and the discount variable in the list. So here is an image of the list:[list with items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgDiU.png), so for each list item and subitems, there's a button which must open a popup and pass the variables belonging to that listitem, like names and discount variable into the form input field, so the user can adjust it from the old value. I use javascript to open and close the form, and want it also to put the php variables (obtained from a database) into that form. So here is my piece of code:

javascript:

```
<script>
function updatepopup(**$name**, $discount){
    document.getElementById("updatedata").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("fnaam").value = **$name**";
    document.getElementById("fkort").value = $discount;
}

function closeform(){
    document.getElementById("updatedata").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

php:

```
<ol class='tree'> "; 
    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo "  ";
    echo '
    <li>
    <label for="subfolder2">'.$category['name'].'</label>
    <label>  '.$category['discount'].'%</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">

    <form id="updatedata" method="POST">
        <label for="fnaam">Naam: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fnaam" name="fnaam" value="'.$category['name'].'">

        <label for="fkort">Korting</label>
        <input type="number" id="fkort" name="fkort" value="'.$category['discount'].'">
        
        <button id="closebutton" onclick="closeform()">X</button>
        <button type= "submit"> </button>
    </form>

    <button onclick="updatepopup()"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
    ';
    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }
    $currLevel++; 
    createTreeView ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);
    $currLevel--;               
    }
}

if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo "<li><button>+</button></li></li>
</ol>";
}
?>
```

So I have read many solutions to pass a string to a javascript function but not a single one would help. I only get something like that done with numbers, but I also want to sent a string into that input field.
So this is what I want to get: [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTCxv.png)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. What's the actual vs expected result?

Comment: What I now get, is nothing just like the image above. What I actualy want to get is the second image, (what I want)

Comment: You changed the structure of your question. Couple of notes: `id` attribute values can only be used **once**. ID's need to be unique, otherwise their use is lost. I'd suggest only using a single `updatedata` form, not one per list item, like you had in your original structure.

Comment: So how would you than pass the php vars to that form on the click of a button in the list?

Comment: Wouldn't you pass those variables in the call to `updatepopup()` rather than set them as arguments in its definition? `<button onclick="updatepopup(phpNameVar,phpDiscountVar);"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>`. Then your function definition would be `function updatepopup(name, discount){...`

Comment: @mykaf How would you do that with: ```<php echo '<button onclick="updatepopup()">Some text</button> ?>``` where in updatepopup, these two vars must be placed: ```$categories['name']``` and ```$categories['discount']``` ?

Comment: As the arguments? `updatepopup("$categories['name']",$categories['discount'])`?

Comment: yes and no, please rewrite the whole line from < to > filled with the vars as arguments

Comment: that only works for numbers by the way, and not for string variables. That's when I make it this way: ```<button onclick="updatepopup('.$category['name'].', '.$category['discount'].')">Mybutton</button>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix PHP with JavaScript, which should be avoided if possible. There are other ways to pass PHP values to JavaScript, like setting them as HTML attributes.

My approach would be to create a `<form>` element for each list item and output your PHP `$category` values in hidden `<input />` elements.

```
<!-- Start list -->
<ol class='tree'> 
  <li>
    <form class="js-update-data">
      <label for="subfolder2"><?= $category['name']; ?></label>
      <span><?= $category['discount']; ?>%</span>

      <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $category["name"]; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="<?= $category["discount"]; ?>" />

      <button type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
    </form>

    <!-- Nested list -->
    <ol class='tree'> 
      <li>
        <form class="js-update-data">
          <!-- Structure for every list item.. -->
        </form>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<!-- End list -->

<!-- Form to show/hide & update -->
<form id="updatedata" method="POST">
  <label for="fnaam">Naam: </label>
  <input type="text" id="fnaam" name="fnaam" value="">

  <label for="fkort">Korting</label>
  <input type="number" id="fkort" name="fkort" value="">
        
  <button type="button" id="closebutton">X</button>
  <button type="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

Then listen for `submit` events on these forms. When a form gets submitted, make sure the `preventDefault()` method on the event is called. This will prevent a reload of the page and allows you to write your own behavior.

Extract the values from the submitted form and pass them to your `updatepopup` function.

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.js-update-data');

for (const form of forms) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const name = formData.get('name');
    const discount = formData.get('discount');

    updatepopup(name, discount);
  });
}

const closeButton = document.getElementById("closebutton");
closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeform);

function updatepopup(name, discount){
  document.getElementById("updatedata").display = "block";
  document.getElementById("fnaam").value = name;
  document.getElementById("fkort").value = discount;
}

function closeform(){
  document.getElementById("updatedata").style.display = "none";
}
```

### Runnable example

This example runs with pre-filled values. The only job you have is to set the values in the right spot.

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.js-update-data');

for (const form of forms) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const name = formData.get('name');
    const discount = formData.get('discount');

    updatepopup(name, discount);
  });
}

const closeButton = document.getElementById("closebutton");
closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeform);

function updatepopup(name, discount){
  document.getElementById("updatedata").hidden = false;
  document.getElementById("fnaam").value = name;
  document.getElementById("fkort").value = discount;
}

function closeform(){
  document.getElementById("updatedata").hidden = true;
}
```

```css
form[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start list -->
<ol class='tree'> 
  <li>
    <form class="js-update-data">
      <label for="subfolder2">Test 1</label>
      <span>25%</span>

      <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test 1"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="25" />

      <button type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>edit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Nested list -->
    <ol class='tree'> 
      <li>
        <form class="js-update-data">
          <label for="subfolder2">Test 2</label>
          <span>13%</span>

          <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">
          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test 2"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="13" />

          <button type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square">edit</i></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <form class="js-update-data">
      <label for="subfolder2">Test 4</label>
      <span>80%</span>

      <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test 4"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="80" />

      <button type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>edit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Nested list -->
    <ol class='tree'> 
      <li>
        <form class="js-update-data">
          <label for="subfolder2">Test 3</label>
          <span>50%</span>

          <input type="checkbox" name="subfolder2">
          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Test 3"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="50" />

          <button type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>edit</button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<!-- End list -->

<!-- Form to show/hide & update -->
<form id="updatedata" method="POST" hidden>
  <label for="fnaam">Naam: </label>
  <input type="text" id="fnaam" name="fnaam" value="">

  <label for="fkort">Korting</label>
  <input type="number" id="fkort" name="fkort" value="">
        
  <button type="button" id="closebutton">X</button>
  <button type="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It sure is. OP's solution isn't really much different other than it outputs both values in a single button. A middle ground would be to output the values as `data-attributes` on the button. If you *would* use event listeners instead of inline event handlers, then you *should*. We're responsible for giving the right example. And I mean no offense.

Comment: how? Can you give an example?

Comment: How would you do that in the following case: The list contains sublists, which are created by a  PHP function in this way:   ```if ($currentParent == category['parent_id']) {                       
    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo "
<ol class='tree'> "; 
    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo "  ";
    echo '
    <li>
    <label for="subfolder2">'.$category['name'].'</label>
    <label>  '.$category['discount'].'%</label>
    <form id="updatedata" method="POST">
    ...
    </form>

    <button onclick="updatepopup()"></button>
    ';```

Comment: Are you referring to my example above or the `data-attributes`? In theory all your list items should have the same markup, regardless of level.

Comment: Am referring to the example above. So is there a way to bind a button to each list item, which displays a popup with a form, and sends the name and other variables to the form?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the example does. Have you tried it? You would have to output this structure for each `<li>` element in your nested lists.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it didn't solve the question. I can create all forms with php that works fine, but that I only want to hide or popup the form with javascript, so there are the buttons with the pen (see the 'list with items' image above), which should do that.

Comment: I've expanded the example to demonstrate a bigger picture. There will be multiple forms in your code, but only one `updatedata` form. The `updatedata` form will be shown or hidden based on clicking any of the *pen* icons. JS will then *copy* the values from the form in the list item and set them in the `updatedata` form.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! It works, also for my specific case! I have only one question, the number type input in the form, will not work as number input, so the arrows aren't showing up

Comment: how would you do it with two forms @Emiel Zuurbier? , because when I add an event to that submit button, both the forms will not work because of this line I think: ```adform.addEventListener('submit', event=> {
        event.preventDefault();``` this for the adform of adforms const.

Comment: Join me in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/249725/jan-peter-poppe?tab=general) so we can have a chat on this.

Comment: I cannot talk in the chatroom because I have not enough reputation. Would you please help me to make a better reputation?

Comment: Still need 7 reputation...

Comment: Then you're only option is to create a new question.